# Tratar campo vazio mesmo contendo espaços

Tags: java, swing

Fiz um conversor de temperatura de Celsius para Fahrenheit, estou querendo tratar se no `JTextField` for diferente de 0, exibir a temperatura em fahrenheit, mas aparece 0.0 até quando está vazio, com espaços inserido nesse campo.

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        double resultado = 0, valor1;

        if(e.getSource() == btnOk) {
            if(!text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
               try {
                   valor1 = Double.parseDouble(text1.getText()); 
                   resultado = valor1 * 1.8 + 32;

                }catch(NumberFormatException e1) {}
                    text2.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a intenção é não deixar validar se a String está vazio ou com espaços apenas, tente aplicar [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) para remover espaços em branco:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        double resultado = 0, valor1;
        String fieldText = text1.getText().trim();

        if(e.getSource() == btnOk) {
            if(!fieldText.isEmpty()) {
               try {
                   valor1 = Double.parseDouble(fieldText); 
                   resultado = valor1 * 1.8 + 32;

                }catch(NumberFormatException e1) {}
                    text2.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));


   }
```

> Obs.: O trim() não remove espaços em branco por entre os caracteres da string, somente os que estiverem no inicio e final. Se for passada uma string somente com espaços em branco para este método, o resultado será uma string vazia.

Comment: Qual a utilidade aqui  || fieldText.equals("0") ?

Comment: @user67285 a validação é não estar em branco e ser diferente de zero ne? isso ai valida se o valor informado é zero. Fiz uma correção, deveria ser diferente de zero.

Comment: Era só os espaços mesmo.

Comment: @user67285 bom, então eu pequei pelo excesso :D  é só remover essa validação que vai funcionar certinho.